# Is it possible to use a dictionary in a mock method with Moq in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a service interface (**IService**) and a concrete class that implements the interface, which has the following methods:

```
string UploadText(string bucketName, string blobName, string text);
string DownloadText(string bucketName, string blobName);
bool IsExistent(string bucketName, string blobName); // check whether the blob exists in the bucket
```

**In my unit test with a mock object:**

```
var mockSvc = new Mock<IService>();
mockSvc.Setup(svc => svc.IsExistent(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(....); // is there a way to use a dictionary as store in this mock method ?
```

So in my mock, I would like to use a dictionary of dictionaries to represent the structure `[bucketName: [blobName : text]]`. Is there a way to initialize a dictionary for the mock method to store test data?

Comment: That sounds like you just need to implement a Fake instead of mocking like `FakeService : IService` and then using a dictionary internally for storing the data.

Comment: You could declare you dictionary of dictionaries in the test class and then do appropriate things in your Retuns to work with shared dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: You could use `Return(Func)` methods backed by local var dictionary to archive this using moq...

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit of work, but I'd still consider it easier to read and use then setting up a Mock.

```
public class DictionaryServiceDouble : Dictionary<string, string>, IService
{
    public string UploadText(string bucketName, string blobName, string text)
    {
        this[GetKey(bucketName, blobName)] = text;
        return text; // Is this what it's supposed to return?
    }

    public string DownloadText(string bucketName, string blobName)
    {
        // This is a little bit problematic if you want to test the behavior
        // when downloading something that doesn't exist.
        // This will work fine on the happy path. But on the "sad" path
        // this doesn't ensure that the double will behave like the real
        // implementation. 
        return this[GetKey(bucketName, blobName)];
    }

    public bool IsExistent(string bucketName, string blobName)
    {
        return ContainsKey(GetKey(bucketName, blobName));
    }

    private string GetKey(string bucketName, string blobName) => $"{bucketName}:{blobName}";
}
```

Now you can initialize it either by adding to the base dictionary directly or, better, by calling the `UploadText` method.

In my experience, mocks are great for some things, but they're not so great for anything complex. It tends to result in complex setup that gets repeated. If we want to reuse something that behaves a certain way then writing a class is easier to do and easier to understand.

Comment: Some people would say it is controversial to inherit from `Dictionary<,>`. You could also just hold a `Dictionary<,>` as a field in your class.

Comment: I'd normally agree. Because it's a test double i wouldn't be as concerned. I thought about it but decided to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you do

```
mockSvc.Setup(svc => svc.IsExistent(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
  .Returns((string bucketName, string blobName) => yourDictionary[bucketName][blobName]);
```

(just an example). If you want more complex logic, you can have a `{ … }` body in the `.Returns` method (it just needs any delegate, does not need to be convertible into an expression tree):

```
mockSvc.Setup(svc => svc.IsExistent(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
  .Returns((string bucketName, string blobName) =>
  {
    var isKnownBucket = yourDictionary.TryGetValue(bucketName, out var blobName);
    // more logic here
    return retValue;
  });
```